# Double integral polar coordinates - boundaries problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to calculate the surface of the area between $$\frac{(x-2)^2}{9} + \frac{(y+1)^2}{4} \le 1$$ and $$y \ge 0$$

Let's introduce polar coordinates:

$$x-2 = 3r\cos(\phi)$$
$$y+1 = 2r\sin(\phi)$$
$$|J| = 6r$$

Substituting this in the first inequality we get that $r^2 \le 1$, which means $r \in [0,1]$ for now.

Now here's the problem. In the second inequality we have:

$$r\sin(\phi) \ge 0$$

As $r$ is already greater or equal to zero, we have that $\sin(\phi) \ge 0$, and thus that $\phi \in [0, \pi]$

One can also see this by drawing a picture, the line $y=0$ is the x axis and we get that it's greater than zero above the x axis, which is from $0$ to $\pi$

Substituting this, I get the following double integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1} 6rdrd\phi$$ and when I solve it I get that the solution is $3\pi$. However, my workbook states that the solution is $2\pi - \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Can anyone help me understand where I might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that

$y = 2 r \sin \phi - 1 \geq 0 \implies r \geq \dfrac{1}{2\sin\phi}$. So the lower bound of $r$ is not zero as you are between a line and the circumference.

Also to find bounds of $\phi$, plug in $r = 1$.

So, $\sin \phi = \dfrac{1}{2} \implies \dfrac{\pi}{6} \leq \phi \leq \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I came to a similar conclusion as you did following the previous answer on this question, but I had trouble figuring out the bounds for the angle. You got the same bounds for $\phi$ as my workbook, but they did it by solving the above system of equations for $y=0$ which is infinitely more tedious than taking $r=1$. 

My question is: Can I always take $r=1$ to figure out the bounds for the angle $\phi$?

Comment: In general, when you are in polar coordinates, to find the bounds of $\theta$, you have to look at the intersection points, right? That means you will take the radius at the circumference, which in this case is $1$.

Comment: I understand about intersection points, but what does "radius at the circumference" mean? I can't get my mind around it

Comment: If you take a circle with radius $1$ and you are talking about area, it will include all interior points as well, right? So we say $0 \leq r \leq 1$ but at intersection with the circle $r = 1$, right?

Answer (score 2):

Since $y+1 = 2r\sin(\phi)$, then
$$y\ge0\iff 2r\sin(\phi)-1\ge0 \iff \sin(\phi)\ge \frac{1}{2r}.$$
Be careful, you have traslated the center of the polar coordinates to the center of the ellipse